# Yii model relation not working

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-relations

i have got 2 table where i have to relation between this two

```
-------------------           -----------------
|    preceptor    |           |       bio     |
|-----------------|           |---------------|
| Preceptor_id    |           | bio_id        |
| Preceptor_name  |           | Preceptor_ID  |
| wat_id          |           | Preceptor_ID1 |
-------------------           | Preceptor_ID2 |
                              -----------------
```

in "bio" model i write like this

```
public function getPreceptor(){
    return $this->hasOne(Preceptor::className(),['Preceptor_id'=>'Preceptor_ID']);
}
public function getPreceptorName(){
    return $this->preceptor->Preceptor_name;
}

public function getPreceptorID1(){
    return $this->hasOne(Preceptor::className(),['Preceptor_id'=>'Preceptor_ID1']);
}
public function getPreceptorID1Name(){
    return $this->preceptor->Preceptor_name;
}

public function getPreceptorID2(){
    return $this->hasOne(Preceptor::className(),['Preceptor_id'=>'Preceptor_ID2']);
}
public function getPreceptorID2Name(){
    return $this->preceptor->Preceptor_name;
}
```

and in "preceptor" model i write like this

```
public function getBio(){
    return $this->hasOne(Bio::className(), ['Preceptor_ID' => 'Preceptor_id']);
}

public function getBios0(){
    return $this->hasOne(Bio::className(), ['Preceptor_ID1' => 'Preceptor_id']);
}

public function getBios1(){
    return $this->hasOne(Bio::className(), ['Preceptor_ID2' => 'Preceptor_id']);
}
```

But my problem is when i show it in bio view it only show "Preceptor_ID" value in all 3 field so how can i show both "Preceptor_ID1" & "Preceptor_ID2"

Comment: Show your view as well.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta  in yii 2 advance

Comment: @ttdijkstra my view is

 <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [           
            'Preceptor_ID',
            'Preceptor_ID1',
            'Preceptor_ID2',
        ], ]) ?>

Comment: In the bio view you specify, you don't use relations to display the data. Its just the data thats stored in the bio table. Are you sure they have different values in the db?

Comment: @ttdijkstra yes there is different pk in bio table

Comment: A pk has differing values per definition. I meant the foreign perceptor keys. I.e. the displayed record has different values in the Preceptor_ID, Preceptor_ID1, Preceptor_ID2 fields.

Comment: @ttdijkstra thank you for your so much for helping now it work properly ^^
yup it have different foreign key :)

Comment: sure @ttdijkstra thankQ once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bio model you specify the same relations when requesting the name for differing preceptors. It should be like below:

```
public function getPreceptorID#Name() {
    return $this->preceptorID#->name;
}
```

This way of requesting data is very redundant. You should just define the relation and request the name in the view like `$bio->preceptorID#->name`.